# Min3d doesn't show anything (in sample from min3d wiki)

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to create a simple Android application using [min3d library](http://code.google.com/p/min3d)

Previously I have downloaded apk file from market with examples of min3d library. Every example in this application works fine on real phone. It means phone has not problems with 3d.

I have chekouted source code of min3d with examples and created simple Android application with single activity copypasted from examples:

```
import min3d.core.Object3dContainer;
import min3d.core.RendererActivity;
import min3d.objectPrimitives.Box;
import min3d.vos.Light;

public class ExampleMostMinimal extends RendererActivity {
    Object3dContainer _cube;

    public void initScene() 
    {
        scene.lights().add( new Light() );
        _cube = new Box(1,1,1, null, true,true,false);
        _cube.colorMaterialEnabled(false);
        scene.addChild(_cube);
    }

    @Override 
    public void updateScene() 
    {
        _cube.rotation().y++;
    }
}
```

But when application launched it shows title bar and black screen.

Please, help.

Comment: I have worked in min3d Framework.It will works fine for me. While loading the model it will took time to display until that it shows black screen. Can you please explain little more???

Comment: Thank you for comment.
I compared the behavior of the sample from the Android Market, and samlpe, I compiled. They're exactly the same. But my example shows only black screen.
May be problem in my instance of min3d framework? I've got it from NyARToolkit sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.

The reason was in source of min3d files. I've got framework files from example of [nyARToolkit](http://nyatla.jp/nyartoolkit/wp/) framework.

When I replaced the files by files checked out from min3d google repository, problem was resolved.

p.s. I copied files from example because min3d in example of nyARToolkit works fine.