# min3D code is showing just black screen

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to create a 3D animation using min3D with the project in code.google.com

http://code.google.com/p/min3d/source/browse/trunk/sampleProjects/min3dSampleProject1/src/min3d/sampleProject1/ExampleRotatingPlanets.java

I have downloaded the Activity file and picture files, I have declared the activity in manifest file as

```
         <activity android:name=".Animation_3dActivity"      android:label="@string/app_name">
             <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>
```

I am using android minSDKVersion as 11.

But when I open the activity in emulator, it is just showing the title bar and a black screen.

With reference to the question in stack overflow,

[Min3d doesn't show anything (in sample from min3d wiki)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914120/min3d-doesnt-show-anything-in-sample-from-min3d-wiki)

It was mentioned that min3D jar has some problem and need to be downloaded again. I replaced with 2-3 jars the problem is still the same.

Can someone please let me know what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the min3D code had some problem. I just copied the min3Daccelorometer example from google and copy pasted  the min3D source files. It worked well.